# Why does Dividing By Zero not crash in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I think that the following code should crash because I am performing an integer division by zero:

```dart
int n = 42;
eatCake(n / 0);
```

Why does dividing by zero not crash my app?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The key here is that `n / 0` is **not *integer* division**.

Dart automatically performs `double` division and the `double` type has the [`double.infinity` constant](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.0/dart-core/double/infinity-constant.html). This means that `print(n / 0)` will yield `Infinity`.
Furthermore, `double.infinity` is actually defined as `1.0 / 0.0`.

If you use integer division instead, you will receive an [`IntegerDivisionByZeroException`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.0/dart-core/IntegerDivisionByZeroException-class.html):

```dart
print(n ~/ 0); // <- IntegerDivisionByZeroException
```